# Grep the nmap output

Tags: linux, grep, pipe, nmap

I have output my nmap result to a file called **test.txt** and it looks like this:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.5
Host is up (0.13s latency).
PORT    STATE  SERVICE VERSION
23/tcp   open  telnet  Linux telnetd
--
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.7
Host is up (0.13s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE    VERSION
80/tcp  open  http       Popper
--
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.20
Host is up (0.13s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE VERSION
110/tcp open  pop3    Dove
```

I want to output the results from the file in my terminal using grep and pipe that displays the result in format: IP address followed by the open ports like this:

```
192.168.10.2
80
223
53
192.168.10.7
80
223
```

Comment: Good sample data and required output (pluse-uno!), but you forgot to show your code (minus-uno!).  Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service. Just about any attempt to solve your problem will show that you aren't just looking for someone to do it for you. To give you a hint, you could use `ncat ... | sed 's/Nmap scan report for //;s/Host is up [(]//'` to  remove unneeded header info. Use what I have supplied to extend it to get rid of all uneeded header info  **and update your Q**. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do the following:

1. Get a regular expression to match ip's and ports for the nmap output. You can take advantage of the positions of both, i.e ports are at the beginning of the line(`^`) and end with a '`/`' character, and ip's are the last item on the line(`$`).
2. Use `grep -o` to look for any of that regular expressions (look at the OR operator on the regex (`|`)). This will reduce the output to just the matches.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/Nmap scan report for //' | sed '/Host is/d' | sed '/Not shown/d' | sed '/All/d' | sed '/PORT /d' | cut -f1 -d"/" | sed '/^$/d' | sed '/--/d'
```

For `nmap -F 192.168.0.1/24 > test.txt`:

```
cat test.txt | tail -n+3 | sed '/Nmap done/d' | awk 'NR>1{print l}{l=$0}' | sed 's/Nmap scan report for //' | sed '/Host is/d' | sed '/Not shown/d' | sed '/All/d' | sed '/PORT /d' | cut -f1 -d"/" | sed '/^$/d'
```

---

**Joke.** It does not make sense... Use **nmap** with XML Output `-oX`.
Read: https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-xml-output.html